# how to implement page navigation in react testing library (Link, a tag, history.push)

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am trying perform Dom testing at  '/test' url page.

my application use `BrowseRouter` from react-router-dom

As following user approach, I want to manually change page to '/test' using `<Link />` from `react-router-dom`, but It doesn't work. I couldn't access page '/test'.

```js
const App = () => {
 return (
    <BrowseRouter>
      <Route key="test" path="/test" component={TestPage} />
      <Route key="index" path="/" component={IndexPage} />
    </BrowseRouter>
 )
}
```

```js
describe(() => {
  it("test TestPage", async () => {
    const history = createMemoryHistory()
    const { queryByTestId } = await waitFor(() => render(
      <Router history={history}>
       <App />
      </Router>
    ))
    userEvent.click(queryByTestId('#to_test_page')) // <Link /> to '/test'
    // history.location.pathname is still '/'
    // window.location.pathname is still '/'
  })
})
```

As a workaround,  I had to wrap my routes with 'MemoryRouter', not a BrowseRouter, help setting entry url to '/test'. But It's not perfect approach for me.

Comment: See the doc https://v5.reactrouter.com/core/guides/testing. Refactor the App component. Move the BrowserRouter into `index.tsx`

Comment: @slideshowp2 Thank you for sharing docs, I solved this using basic `<Router />` as docs said

Answer (score 0):

Try awaiting the click

```
await act(async () => userEvent.click(queryByTestId('#to_test_page')));
```

Comment: You need to say where act is imported from